# "QObject::startTimer: Timers cannot be started from another thread" error, but timer was moved to proper thread before

Tags: multithreading, qt

I am moving object to some thread by this method:

```
void RelayHandler::setThread(QThread *newThread)
{
    this->moveToThread(newThread);
    timer->moveToThread(newThread);
}
```

Then I'm starting timer in some place and check it's thread and object thread:

```
qDebug() << this->thread();
qDebug() << timer->thread();
timer->start();
```

When it's firing, Debug prints:

```
QThread(0x2c1393d2db0)
QThread(0x2c1393d2db0)
QObject::startTimer: Timers cannot be started from another thread
```

What's wrong? Timer and object are in the same thread, but it throws an error and cannot start the timer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What's wrong? Timer and object are in the same thread, but it throws an error and cannot start the timer.

Two things:

1. You're accessing the object (`this`) from a wrong thread, in an unsafe manner.
2. You're calling `timer->start()` from the wrong thread. The code could be modified as follows to make it clear what's expected:

   Q_ASSERT(timer->thread() == QThread::currentThread());
   timer->start();

If you insist on starting the timer from a different thread, the call has to be made thread-safely:

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(timer, [timer]{ 
    Q_ASSERT(timer->thread() == QThread::currentThread());
    timer->start();
});
```